# Proving that first-order PA is not finitely axiomatizable

Tags: logic

I am trying to prove that there is no finite set of first-order sentences that is an axiomatization of PA.

My first attempts naturally aimed at showing that for any finite axiomatization of PA, call it FPA, there is a theorem of PA that FPA does not prove, but I could not get much. It seems that the obvious choice for the theorem of PA that a FPA does not prove is a theorem which is an instance of the induction scheme (or the to the latter equivalent well ordering principle).

Do you have any hints?

Comment: The obvious method is to use compactness to prove that if $PA$ is finitely axiomatized then it's axiomatized by a finite subset of $PA$. Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: The usual way is to show that PA proves the consistency of any finite subtheory of PA.

Comment: @realdonaldtrump How does that use compactness? It's trivial: if $T=\{t_1,...,t_n\}$ axiomatizes PA, let $A_i$ be the finite sets of PA-axioms used to prove $t_i$ (this doesn't need compactness, since proofs by definition are finite); then $A=\bigcup_{1\le i\le n}$ is the desired finite subtheory of PA. And this doesn't answer the question, since we still need to get a contradiction from this somehow. The nontrivial part of the problem is showing, as spaceisdarkgreen says, that PA proves the consistency of each of its finite fragments.

Comment: I guess I don't see a big difference between compactness and that property; each is a simple corollary of the other. My comment was a hint aimed at the OP's apparent doubts as to whether the example should come from within PA or from without.

Comment: In any case, I think the key fact is that within PA we can prove that there is a universal $\Sigma^0_n$ formula for each $n$, that is, a formula $\phi(e, n, \bar a)$ so that for every $\Sigma^0_n$ formula $\psi(n, \bar a)$ there is an $e$ so that PA proves $(\forall n, \bar a)[ \phi(e,n,\bar a) \leftrightarrow \psi(n, \bar a)]$.  This is often called the "satisfaction relation" for $\Sigma^0_n$ formulas.  If PA was finitely axiomatized, it would have a set of axioms that are all $\Sigma^0_n$ for some $n$.   One reference is Richard Kaye, *Models of Peano Arithmetic*, ch 10.